# $y''+2\epsilon y(y+1)=x$, where $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I'm trying to solve $y''+2\epsilon y(y+1)=x$, where $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=0$ using perturbation theory.

Using the substitution $y=y_{0}+y_{1}\epsilon$ I got the series $y=\frac{1}{6}x^{3}-\epsilon(\frac{1}{36}x^{5}+\frac{1}{1008}x^{8})+O(\epsilon ^{2})$.

I used a spreadsheet to solve the ODE with Euler's method and I'm not convinced that this perturbation series matches the numerical solution.

Comment: It seems that there is a mistake in the derivation of the $x^5$ term, the result should be $y\sim \frac{x^3}{6}-\epsilon\left(\frac{x^8}{1008}+\frac{x^5}{60}  \right)$

Comment: Thanks @PaulEnta that seems to make sense since $\frac{2x^3}{6}$ integrated twice would give $\frac{x^5}{60}$ (I got integration and differentiation mixed up causing the mistake). I'll amend my spreadsheet to check if it improves the approximation.